# OptiX was unable to open the disk cache with sufficient privileges

Tags: optix

My program using OptiX crashes with the following error:

```
OptiX API error 1550: OptiX was unable to open the disk cache with sufficient privileges
```

Where is this disk cache located, so that I can fix permissions there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
sudo chmod -R u+rw /var/tmp/OptixCache
```

---

The OptiX cache files had been created by another user first, which resulted in this permission error.

When faced with similar situations, [using `strace`](https://serverfault.com/a/138299) can help locate which files are being opened by a binary:

```
strace -f -e trace=openat <your_binary> <arguments>
```